# Game of might or it might not be?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Here are two linked puzzles:

Puzzle #1 is a riddle:

> I am played in black and white,
>   though probably not a game of might.
>
> Half of the field gets loaded at start
>   with equal forces on either part.
>
> It represents a war with pieces,
>   having soldiers and different animal species.

**Who am I?**

---

Puzzle #2 is linked to the above:

> A fill-in-the-blank:
>
> __, B, N, R, Q, K

*No partial answers, please.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part 1:

> Chess

Since:

I am played in black and white

> Obvious

though probably not a game of might

> Chess requires strategy, not brute force

Half of the field gets loaded at start

> 32 out of 64 squares

with equal forces on either part

> Black and white have the same pieces

It represents a war with pieces

> Obvious

having soldiers and different animal species

> The pieces on the board are commonly referred to as soldiers on a battlefield - and knights are soldiers
> Humans and knights are also different animal species

So part 2:

> You're tricking us! We have to leave it blank!

Since:

> There are 6 types of pieces each with a designation, pawn (no symbol), bishop (B), knight (N), rook (R), queen (Q) and king (K)

Comment: Humans and knights are also different animal species? :)) In some languages pieces are referred as animals( elephant for bishop, horse for knight etc. )

Answer (score 5):

The obvious looking answer would seem to be

> **Chess**

except that "having soldiers and different animal species" doesn't fit well:

> as chess really only has horses, and they're not even called that.
>  Also, this is *far* too obvious an answer, so I sincerely hope it's not Chess.

So I'd offer instead:

> **[Shogi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogi)**

---

Part 1:

```
I am played in black and white
```

> The players in Shogi are "Black" and "White"

```
though probably not a game of might
```

> It's a strategy game won by capturing the king, not by killing all the opponents

```
Half of the field gets loaded at start
with equal forces on either part
```

> This game is played on a $9\times9$ board, and each player begins with 20 pieces -
>  $20+20=40$ is as close to half of $81$ as you can get.
>  Both players have equal forces.

```
It represents a war with pieces
having soldiers and different animal species
```

> There are soldiers ("foot soldiers" and "generals") and ***different*** animal species: "horses" and "dragons"

---

Part 2:

Linked to the above, fill in the following blank:
__, B, N, R, Q, K

> Shogi has bishops, knights, rooks, queens, kings with the familiar letters.
>  It also has "G"old Generals, "S"ilver Generals, "L"ances, and "P"awns,
>  plus promoted "+" versions of most of these.
>
>  So—trick question... the blank would contain, probably: **G, S, L, P**

Comment: good information on a game similar to Chess !